# Command Prompt - Set working directory

Tags: command-prompt

I have a batch file like below. I get user input and set it in a variable. It didn't work if i try to to navigate to a particular folder using that variable.
Can you please help..

```
@echo off

cd\

title Build Batch

cd C:\ProgramData\CodeBase\ 

dir

set /p codeBase=Enter the CodeBase: %=%

@echo Build for %codeBase%

cd\

cd C:\ProgramData\CodeBase\%codeBase%\my_code_folder\build

pause
```

Comment: You may have to qoute the last line like this: "C:\ProgramData\CodeBase\%codeBase%\my_code_folder\build"

Comment: "IT doesn't work" is unfortunately meaningless. You need to tell us what you expected to happen and what did happen.

Comment: Magoo: I mean after printing the value for the variable codeBase, it says Press any key to continue..... And eventually it quits.

Comment: @Visar: No. It didn't work.. :(

Comment: I just tried your code on my machine and "it works", which means it changes folder to C:\ProgramData\CodeBase\%codeBase%\my_code_folder\build.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: _Press any key to continue..._ is normal output message from `pause` command. Try your script with initial `@echo on`.